# Discord. JS bot not starting properly

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to code a Discord bot using discord js. However, when I start it up, there are no error message, only just stays at this screen.

> sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules/discord-leveling/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:245:13
> ═[Discord-Leveling Database Loaded -V1.1.0]═[Support server: https://discord.gg/eBFKDbx]=

I haven't been able to get any help from the internet or from other support servers, so if anybody could help me out it would be much appreciated.

This is my startup code.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
  (async function(){
  const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
  storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));

  console.log('Nintendo Musicians Bot is online!');
  client.user.setActivity('with your mind', {type: 'PLAYING'}).catch(console.error);
});




client.on('message', async message =>{
  client.guilds.cache.get('701787671244046366').emojis.cache.forEach(emoji => console.log(emoji.animated ? '<a:' + emoji.name + ':' + emoji.id + '>' : '<:' + emoji.name + ':' + emoji.id + '>'));
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  currency.add(message.author.id, 1);


   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
   const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
   
   const input = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
   const commandArgs = input.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the last version of discord js update your node js to the last version, discord.js v13 just run with node 16+

Answer (score -1):

You are not using v13. Discord no longer supports queries such as message.author.id instead use interaction.user.id. Read the discord js slash command docs and you should be fine.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect and not sure why did you feel the need to answer a 2-years old question with unrelated stuff like this.

Comment: :) imagine being mad cuz bad

Comment: Imagine what? Who is being mad?

Answer (score -2):

looks like you are using Discord.JS v11. This version is **no longer** supported